# Bipartite graph definition in West's Introduction to graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, definition, set-partition

Why does it say "possibly empty" in the definition of bipartite graph? Wouldn't that mean that every graph is bipartite, moreover I don't think partitionins can have empty sets. Is this a mistake?

[image: definition of bipartite graph]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, although it is not important this definition is from Douglas West's book Introduction to Graph Theory.

Second, of course not every graph is bipartite according to this definition. If one part is empty, the other part cannot contain edges.

Third, it seems to me that the assumption of empty parts allows us to consider a graph with one vertex as bipartite. Then, for example, K$\ddot{\rm o}$nig's theorem does not require any exceptions: A graph is bipartite if and only if it has no
odd cycle.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but the part that really confuses me the most is how k-partite graphs are defined in the book. A few paragraphs later, the author says "A graph G is k-partite if V(G) can be expressed as the union of k (possibly empty) independent sets". Doesn't it then mean that every n-partite graph is also m-partite for m>n?

Comment: You're right, of course. But there's nothing wrong with that in my opinion and it's not much of a price to pay for the convenience we get in return. Pay your attention, how the author of the book writes in the next paragraph about the chromatic number.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "possibly empty" statement answers the question:

*Let $G$ be a graph having two or more vertices which are not connected to each other. Is this a bipartite graph?*

Answer: Yes. Take $A=\{a,b,c\}$ the disconnected vertices and $B=\emptyset$ then clearly $V(G)=A\cup B$.

If we do not assume the "possibly empty" part then this kind of flaws will come up and complicate the matter. I hope you understand. One interesting fact is that one may say taking $A=\{a,b\}$ and $B=\{c\}$ would solve the problem, but does this meet the requirement? I mean none of any member of $A$ is connected to $B$ so separating them by this manner is meaningless. Possibly empty resolves this matter.